# NPOI how to read richtext from cell

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I have to read an XLSX with NPOI. In my xlsx there are cells which they have bold words, there is a way to find those words using NPOI?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you provide some source code that you have tried? Did you get any exception or are you using some documentation for reference?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to loop on each char of the richtext

```
XSSFRichTextString s = (XSSFRichTextString)c.RichStringCellValue;

for (int t = 0; t < s.Length; t++)
{
    var myfont = s.GetFontAtIndex(t);
    if (myfont != null && myfont.IsBold)
        boldCharactersIndex.Add(t); // boldCharactersIndex is a list of indexes with bold chars
}
```